# resize issue in swt

Tags: java, user-interface, resize, swt, grid-layout

I am quite new to SWT programming. I have a `GridLayout`. When i first launch the GUI, it only displays one `Button` in the top left corner. If I resize it (make the window either bigger or smaller), I get the GUI I want. I have tinkered with the constructor and the `open()` method but each change I make makes no difference.

```
       // constructor
public MyGuiApp(){
    super();
    shell = new Shell();
    shell.setSize(250, 300);

     // the open method
public void open() {
    Display display = Display.getDefault();
    createContents();
    shell.open();
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,true));


     // instantiation 
        public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        MyGuiApp window = new MyGuiApp();
        window.open();
```

Comment: Could you please post the complete code?

Comment: Try setting the layout before you open the shell.

Comment: good suggestion- what i needed to do was move some of the initialisations from the constructor and open methods to createContents().

Comment: @BrianFeran Next time, post code that compiles. Otherwise it is very hard to see what goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The code should be:

```
Display display = Display.getDefault();
Shell shell = new Shell(display);
shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, true));
createContents(shell);
shell.pack();
shell.open();
```

You are missing the `shell.pack();` which will size the shell according to its content.

---

BTW: [Here](http://www.java-forums.org/java-tip/5028-swt-code-template.html) is a very nice template that can be used as starting point for almost any SWT application.

Comment: Thanks baz, good suggestion- what i needed to do was move some of the initialisations from the constructor and open methods to createContents().